Keycloak: how to get token containing all clients a users is assigned to
I did built some kind of jumpsite/portal "MYAPPS" which resides inside an apache and which is secured by mod_auth_openidc which works fine so far using this apache vhost config
[...]

OIDCProviderMetadataURL        https://keycloak.srv/realms/XXXXXXXX/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCRedirectURI                https://keycloak.srv/myapps/redirect_uri
OIDCClientID                   MYAPPS
OIDCClientSecret               1234567890123456789
OIDCProviderTokenEndpointAuth  client_secret_basic
OIDCRemoteUserClaim            email
OIDCScope                      "openid email profile roles groups"

[...]

<Location /myapps>
                AuthType openid-connect
                Require valid-user
</Location>   

[...]

Inside my MYAPPS application I do have IFrame components which should actually load other applications hosted on different apache hosts which are also either protected by mod_auth_openidc or have some kind of other keycloak auth mechanism.
For each of my web-applications (MYAPPS, iframed-app-1,  iframed-app-2, ...) I do have a separate Client config within keycloak. All Clients are inside same REALM within keycloak.
When I do access each web-application one after another (by directly browsing to URL) everything works as expected:

accessing first webapp (MYAPPS) -> redirects me keycloak login
after successfull log in to keycloak I get redirected to my first webapp (MYAPPS)
accessing second webapp (iframed-app1) -> I dont get redirected to keycloak but become directly enabled to use iframed-app1
accessing third webapp (iframed-app2) -> I dont get redirected to keycloak but become directly enabled to use iframed-app2

--> so far so good

But I want to access iframed-app1 and iframed-app2 from MYAPPS using an IFrame. Currently I get this behavior:

accessing first webapp (MYAPPS) -> redirects me keycloak login
after successfull log in to keycloak I get redirected to my first webapp (MYAPPS)
accessing second webapp (iframed-app1) from IFrame within MYAPPS I do get ( inside iframe):


Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
(from my webserver hosting iframed-app1)

The same applies when I try to access iframed-app2 inside a different iframe within MYAPPS

I do understand my MYAPPS webapp is using keycloak's clientID "MYAPPS" and my other webapps use their own keycloak clientIDs. And once I directly access my iframed-apps my token somewhat gets "expanded" to contain more clients.
I also can see this behavior when I check my keycloak accounts->applications page (https://keycloak.srv/realms/XXXX/account/#/applications). The list of applications get longer if I directly use the appropriate URL and directly access my webapps.

Main question is: How can I manage to have all clients inside my token after initial successful login to keycloak ?
Because once I do have all my "account/#/applications" listed (due to manully surf to their direct URLs) I am able to see all iframed-apps within IFrame inside MYAPPS.

I already played with different URLs to achieve some kind of redirects from keycloak to my webapps which might cause my token to get filled up like e.g.:

https://keycloak.srv/realms/XXXX/account/?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
https://keycloak.srv/realms/XXXXX/protocol/openid-connect/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

But this idea turned out to be not working as I hoped/expected
I also tried to create a keycloak client scope "openid" and added mappers like "clients roles" and "audience resolve" to this client scope which I then added to my keycloak client config, because I thought this is how it would work. But still no luck going this direction

Any kind of help or hint would really be appreciated !
Cheers
majo
